# not able to use file_get_contents() in php

Tags: php

I am making a new script but when I use this

```
$bal= file_get_contents('http://mcent1.nptemp.net/t.php?mobileno='.$no.'&pass='.$pwd');
echo "<br>Balance After:".$fbal;
```

I am unable to get `bal` this code is used to get balance from user imputed details but I am not even seeing the option to enter mobile number and password .

Comment: file_get_contents('http://mcent1.nptemp.net/t.php?mobileno='.$no.'&pass='.$pwd') <<< The last quote shouldn't be there.

Comment: I have checked not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Two things:-*

*1.Quotes need to be taken care and*

*2.`$fbal` is no where defined. So code should be:-*

```
$bal= file_get_contents("http://mcent1.nptemp.net/t.php?mobileno=$no&pass=$pwd"); // use only double quotes
echo "<br>Balance After:".$bal; // $fbal is no where in the context so use $bal
```

Or this should be also worked for you:-

```
$bal= file_get_contents('http://mcent1.nptemp.net/t.php?mobileno='.$no.'&pass='.$pwd); // remove the last single quote
echo "<br>Balance After:".$bal;// $fbal is no where in the context so use $bal
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra single quote at the end. Also, `$fbal` is not defined, it's most probably a typo of `$bal`.

```
$bal= file_get_contents('http://mcent1.nptemp.net/t.php?mobileno='.$no.'&pass='.$pwd);

echo "<br>Balance After:".$bal;
```

Comment: just kidding. Keep up the good work

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an apostrophe that isn't required and will be throwing an error.

Also, `$fbal` is undefined.

```
$bal = file_get_contents('http://mcent1.nptemp.net/t.php?mobileno='.$no.'&pass='.$pwd);
echo "<br>Balance After:".$bal;
```

Comment: Nice catch after my update ($fbal).

Comment: I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Anant +1 for your answer too ;-)

Comment: Hey no issue, At-least you guys  pointed first one correctly. and then second one too

Comment: to you both +10 from my side

Answer (score 1):

check `php.ini` and find `allow_url_fopen` rule. It should be enabled

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php